# Memory Model of Process and thread

Tags: multithreading, process

All:

I am pretty new to OS, most beginner tutorials about Process and Thread are talking about their relationship from conceptual perspective. But what I am wondering if some one could use some simple example to illustrate how does the process generated and arranged in memory, how the threads generated inside process and how to be arranged in memory and how a task has been executed?

And I also wonder: so the process itself actually is not a working unit, it is the threading which actually run the task, the process is just a namespace container which contains all threads and shared variables, is that right?

Thanks